# Cannot print $variables using template_preprocess_views_view_rss() in readable format

Tags: views, 8, feeds

How can I print out $variables from template_preprocess_views_view_rss() in a readable format?  The RSS view page uses a non-rendering format and is impossible to read. I need to manipulate the feed because no D8 RSS module is stable at this point.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use `kint()` and `print_r()` with `array_keys()` to locate all the objects for manipulation.  In some cases I was debugging with the kint() display and in others just looking at plain text by using the other mentioned functions.

For note the `template_views_view_rss()` and `template_views_view_row_rss()` hooks are located in view.theme.inc (core) and no where in documentation on drupal.org for D8.  I believe they are soon to be deprecated.

```
// Specific feed filter
if( $variables['view']->id() == 'blog' && $variables['view']->current_display == 'feed_1') {
  // Iterate rows
  foreach($variables['rows'] as $key_1 => $row) {
    // Do stuff
    foreach($row['#row']->elements as $key_2 =>  $element) {
      // Do stuff
    }
  }
}
```